# Let G^op be the set G (multiplicative group) equipped with a new operation ∗ defined by a∗b = ba: 2 questions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a multiplicative group.  Let Gop be the set G equipped with a new operation ∗ defined by a∗b = ba.

```
(a) Prove that Gop is a group.   I'M STUCK TRYING TO SHOW INVERSES EXIST (HAVE EVERYTHING ELSE)

(b) Prove that G ≅ Gop. [Hint: Corollary 7.6 may be helpful:  a,b∈G → 1. (ab)-1 = b-1a-1, 2. (a-1)-1=a]
 ONCE I'VE FINISHED (a) ABOVE, THEN I'VE PROVED IT IS A GROUP.    WHAT ELSE DO I NEED TO SHOW FOR THIS PART?
```

Comment: Hint for (a): what is $a\star a^{-1}$? ($a^{-1} \in G^{op}$ since $a^{-1} \in G$).

Comment: Hey Alex, can I ask you a question on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The comment should suffice for (a), let us know if you're still stuck.

Hint for (b): using the given corollary, we can see that flipping the order of multiplication has something to do with inverses. So try $\phi : G \to G^{op}$ with $a \mapsto a^{-1}$. Using the second part of the corollary and the fact that every element of $G$ has a unique inverse, you can show that this is a bijection. Then, can you show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, that is, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) * \phi(b)$? You will need to use the first part of the corollary.